# converting sumif forimula from excel to macro vba - Prolem 2 : converting cell range

Tags: excel, formula

When I'm running code below

```
Sub test2() Dim i, 
Rownumber As Integer 
Rownumber = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To Rownumber

            Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(i, 3).Formula = "=sumif(Sheet3!$A$2:$A$10, Sheet4!A2, Sheet3!$B$2:$B$10)"

        Next i
         End Sub
```

The macro is running well, but when I convert it into macro VBA:

```
Sub test2()
Dim i, Rownumber As Integer
Rownumber = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Rownumber

        Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(i, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:A10"), Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(2, 1), Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B2:B10"))

    Next i

End Sub
```

It gives me error --> **run type error 13, type missmatch**

Any clues why this happens and how to fix it? -- ***cased closed***

Thanks

***PROBLEM NO 2***

code below is running well when it's executes :

```
 For j = 3 To Colnumber

            For i = 2 To Rownumber
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheets("3G").**Range("F2:F6991")**, Sheets("3G").Range("E2:E6991"), Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1))


            Next i

        Next j
```

but why when i change it onto :

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheets("3G").**Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(6991, 6))**, Sheets("3G").Range("E2:E6991"), Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1))
```

it gave me error : error 1004, application defined or defined-object error ??

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SumIf` is not `SumIfs`. The order of the Arguments is different thus resulting in an error.

`SumIfs` starts with the range to be summed up (multi cell range) folowed by pairs of Criteria ranges  (multi cell range) and Criteria (single cell).

`SumIf` starts with the Criteria Range then the Criteria (single cell) then the range to be summed up (multi cell range).

Fix it by swapping the order of the Arguments accordingly OR using the other function (`SumIf` not `SumIfs`)